# AngularJS chaining $http get requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

New to angular. I am trying to call multiple $http get calls and the second call depending on the result and parsed JSON of the first one as follows:

1) Do an $http get request to get a JSON with an array of elements like ["album 1", "album2"]

2) Loop over each item in the array and do a different $http get request to get the track details for that album.

Here is the controller code for the same (incomplete) where I want to achieve this:

```
    var vm = this;
    vm.albums = init;
    vm.albums.tracks = albumTracks;
    vm.newFunction = newFunction;

    return init();

    return albumTracks ();

    function init(){

        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/albums').then(function(responseData){
            // Parse the json data here and display it in the UI
            vm.albums = responseData;
            $log.debug(angular.toJson(responseData, true));

        // For every album, do another get call in the function albumTracks
            for(var i=0; i<vm.albums.length; i++){
                vm.albums.tracks = [];
                vm.albums.tracks.push(albumTracks(vm.albums[i]));
                console.log(vm.albums.tracks);  // This prints on the console as [undefined]
            }

            console.log(vm.albums.tracks);
            return vm.albums;
        })
    }

    function albumTracks(album){
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/albums/'+album).success(function(trackResponse){
            //parse each album and get the track list
            vm.albums.tracks = trackResponse;
            return vm.albums.tracks;
        })
    }
```

Here is how each JSON response looks like:

```
//http://localhost:8080/api/albums/:
 [
  "the-revenant-original-motion-picture-soundtrack",
  "twilight-of-the-ghosts"
 ]

//http://localhost:8080/api/albums/twilight-of-the-ghosts:
[
{
"fileName": "twilight-of-the-ghosts-twilight-of-the-ghosts-01-pinned-to-the-mattress.flac",
"title": "Pinned to the Mattress",
"artists": "Twilight of the Ghosts",
"album": "Twilight of the Ghosts",
"sequenceNumber": 1,
"trackLength": 274
},
 {
"fileName": "twilight-of-the-ghosts-twilight-of-the-ghosts-02-sinking-slowly-slowly-sinking.flac",
"title": "Sinking Slowly Slowly Sinking",
"artists": "Twilight of the Ghosts",
"album": "Twilight of the Ghosts",
"sequenceNumber": 2,
"trackLength": 270
}
and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you will overwrite `tracks` with each `tracksResponse`. You may want to do:

```
vm.album.tracks = vm.album.tracks.concat(trackResponse);
```

Instead, you want to associate the albums and tracks, so use an array of objects for the albums instead of an array of strings:

```
vm.albums = responseData.map(album => ({name: album, tracks: []}));
```

Then, you will pass in the album object which you can update after the tracks request:

```
album.tracks = trackResponse;
```

The `console.log`s will not work where you have them because `$http` is *asynchronous*.

```
let a = "a";
$http.get(() => a = "b");
console.log(a); // logs "a" even though it was written after `a = "b"`
```

This means that if you are depending on the response of the `$http` request for anything you have to do that work in the callback of the request. You probably don't need to do that in this case, though, since updating the `vm` should update your templates automatically because of how Angular works.

Comment: Thanks. Are you also suggesting that I remove the loop I have ? I am a bit lost there. Like should I use an http.get(....).then(function() another http get()) etc ?

Comment: @noobcoder no, the loop is fine. You can do those http requests simultaneously so the asynchronicity is beneficial here

Comment: Thanks again. I dont think I understand the syntax

    responseData.map(album => ({name: album, tracks: []}));

The => is unclear to me. Is that how we create a map object in angular ?

Comment: @noobcoder this is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) -- you may be using a browser that does not support them. Just use the regular `function () {}` syntax instead.

Answer (score 0):

> As per my Knowledge You may need to angular-loop instead of 'for'loop
>   where you can attach trackers with out Some more coding and chaos.

```
vm.albumsWithTrackers = []; // New Variable Defining needed.

//http://localhost:8080/api/albums/: // it is fine Json but with some define attributes it looks good 
                 [
                  "the-revenant-original-motion-picture-soundtrack",
                  "twilight-of-the-ghosts"
                 ]

      //  Albums With attributes Defined :- 

        [
          "id":"the-revenant-original-motion-picture-soundtrack",
          "id":"twilight-of-the-ghosts"
         ]

        angular.forEach(vm.albums, function (album, key) {
                    album.tracks.push(albumTracks(album));  // attaching only trackers to current album on loop 
                    vm.albumsWithTrackers.push(album); // pushing Album to new defined variable
                    console.log(album.tracks);  
                    });
                });
               console.log(vm.albumsWithTrackers);//album with attached trackers.
            return vm.albumsWithTrackers;

    function albumTracks(album){
            $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/albums/'+album.id).success(function(trackResponse){
                 return trackResponse; //send trackers response directly
            })
        }
```

I hope this approach Will help to sort Your issue  :-)
Thanks.

Comment: I tried the angular forEach but the problem is, it doesn't read the array in order. For instance, if my albums array is [album1, album2], for some unknown reason to me, it reads album 2 first and then album1

Comment: it is not looping because there is no object in Loop it loops when [{obj1},{obj2}]. you have a confirmed object model with response as array ? I Mean you dont wanna change the model and response and you are expecting Out put with this response ? But  Angular and Json relationship is all runs on Objects in arrays

Comment: Do you wanna change the resonse array in to array of Objects .. actually that is a good practice you will find it Down the Road .